# iPhone SMS chat bubbles approved in App Sotre?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I want to integrate the iPhone sms like chat bubbles in my application. But when I read more about it I found that this will not be approved by the app store. Is this true? Cant we use chat bubbles in the application?

Here are some links which describes this.

http://www.iphonestalk.com/iphone-app-store-submission-rejectedbecause-of-chat-bubbles-angry-developer-speaks-out-5836/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link, it sounds like it.  Although I would review the full app store review guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (Note: requires you to sign in as an Apple developer).  When you think about it, it makes sense though.  Apple has spent a lot of time designing a unique interface and if they have, in fact, trademarked/patented that style of displaying a two-way chat, there's no way they're going to let you use it.

To be honest with you, I think it's likely more complicated than "yes you can use chat bubbles" or "no you cannot use chat bubbles."  There are probably some fairly specific guidelines that define what Apple has trademarked/protected and what they haven't, hence the suggestion to make them less shiny.  Long and short of it is, if you application looks exactly like the iPhone SMS application, I don't see it fairing well in the review process.

Comment: There are few threads I found which discusses this. So better to be in the safer side I thought of not using it. Thanks for your reply Chris.

Answer (score 5):

The article is over a year old.

There are hundreds, if not thousands of apps in the app store using chat bubble images that look identical to those used in the SMS app.

Some of those apps I use, some of them I created. I've never had a rejection based on the chat bubbles.

Comment: And besides, the only way to _really_ know, is trying. The Apple reviewers are totally unpredictable.